# Как обработать восстановление вкладки?

Tags: javascript

Вкладка браузера закрывается и восстанавливается при помощи <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

В момент её закрытия или восстановления требуется выполнить некоторые действия.
Но обрабатывать переход на другие страницы не надо, поэтому `beforeunload` не подходит.

Гарантируется, что сайт открыт не более чем в одной вкладке.

Как это можно реализовать?

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/37207450/4928642)